# Chrome CSS image transitions affect other elements

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-transitions

I have a menu with images as backgrounds for buttons which animate on hover.
The problem is that when I hover over an image and it gets animated (enlarged and rotated) other elements on page treble a few pixels with no apparent reason.

I have create a JSfiddle hoping that I could reproduce the bug existent on my website (where other images on page got moved) and still give you a not-too-long code.

The result: Well... Instead of images getting that treble is the JSfiddle `result` text that moves with no reason, and the scrollbar from CSS which flickers.

http://jsfiddle.net/AaXyV/1/

**YouTube**: [DEMO VIDEO](http://youtu.be/2sZIRkUpNqw?t=9s) at second 0:10

Bug? Fixes?

Tried in: Chrome 24.0.1312.52 m, in other browsers (including Safari) seems to work ok.

Comment: I don't see any other elements moving. (Chrome 24 m or 26 Canary)

Comment: no bugs here in chrome 24.0.1312.52 on mac OS X 10.8

Comment: Me neither (24.0.1312.52). Do you have any extensions running?

Comment: Hmm... I am on Windows 7, a friend of mine reported the issue too. Look carefully at the Result span in the top corner of the result area while moving your mouse on potatoes and than moving the mouse out of result area (fast).

Comment: I have edited the question, added link to youtube to show the bug.

Comment: Updated, changed to Unlisted, sorry.

Comment: I don't think it's related but I got the first BSOD ever on this 6months old PC after trying lots of times to reproduce that bug in Chrome, before the BSOD there was an error regarding memory accessed by Chrome...

Answer (score 2):

I can't recreate the jittering result span, but I do see the flickering scrollbar.  Looks like it may be a known bug:

[Issue 139928:  CSS transition on the width of an element with display "inline-block" causes jitter](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=139928)

Comment: Try first hovering the span and than move your mouse again over the potatoes.

Comment: The problem is much more visible in my project: http://nefatec.ro/ See top nav bar (over over buttons).

Comment: I was able to see the twitching span when I first loaded the page 30 minutes ago, so I do believe you.  But ever since, no matter what I do, I can't recreate the issue.  Running chrome 24.0.1312.52 m.

Comment: On your page, I see div#catalog1, div#catalog2, and the following table moving right 1-2 pixels during the animation, and then moving back when the animation is complete.  Is that what you are seeing?

Comment: along other things yes (actually no, those divs do not move on the homepage) ... It makes no sense for those divs to move as they are not related in any way...

Comment: On your home page, the issue with the catalog divs and the table is the auto margins.  I am guessing that the browser is recalculating these during the animation.  If you turn the margins off, you should notice the twitch go away.  Since the page is a fixed width, I would suggest putting your left margin a fixed distance.

Comment: It seems like the bug also depends on resolution used. On 1680*1050 I don't see the divs moving but if I change size to 1024*768 I can clearly see the bug.

Comment: On your website, I do see the menu items twitching.  This goes away when I remove the text-align:center style from the div.menu.  Not a fix, but a step closer.

Comment: This is a bit frustrating. The bug is occurring in my site, but when I test your jsfiddle, I don't see the issue. Have you fixed it in the fiddle?

Comment: I haven't been able to recreate it in the fiddle for some time now, as the issue is related to the window, or screens resolution.  The issue might be related to the fact that they are block elements, not inline, and I was going to play with that once I am able to see the problem again.