# CSS first-of-type selector incorrectly applied correctly after chrome update

Tags: css, google-chrome

Yesterday I updated Chrome to version 24, after doing this it seemed the `display:none` attribute I had applied to a selector did not seem to be applied.

I have a first-of-type selector that will apply `display:block`, it seems this is applied to all members of that type except the last one.

When I disabled/enable this css `display` property in the Chrome developer tools the `display:none` does get applied correctly.  The developer tools are even showing `display` to be `none` while still allowing to select the element from the web page

This behavior was working for the previous version of chrome and firefox.

Is there a way I can force to trigger this behavior?

I have currently tried setting a different class apply the display logic in Javascript, but I would prefer to have a CSS solution.

**edit**

There is also a "div {display:block;}" present from "user agent stylesheet", although this is marked as overriden in the developer tools, perhaps this is part of the problem?

Comment: It seems the latest stable version of chrome is 23, May be your current version is beta one. check here http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.in/

Comment: No, the latest stable release of Chrome is 24.0.1312.52, which is what I use. I've never downloaded a beta of Chrome, and I assume it doesn't update itself to a beta from a stable version.

Comment: The update was automatically downloaded, so I assume it is a stable version indeed.

Comment: Chrome 24 seems to be very buggy, I also posted a question yesterday regarding a bug with CSS transitions... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386512/chrome-css-image-transitions-affect-other-elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the issue you are experiencing is to "turn on and off" elements with display:block/none; is probably the rendering issue that Chrome is experiencing from long ago.

Sometimes replace content with display causes a redrawing issue in Chrome and even if the console shows the properties are replaces, it doesn't affects the window and its elements.

Try adding this to the elements you want to hide/show:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

Or if you are using translate for X and Y can simply add:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0); // This affects only the Z preserving X and Y
```

Also you can read what exactly does the transform action to the browser to make it "act" in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529381/what-does-webkit-transform-translate3d0-0-0-exactly-do-apply-to-body) made by Yotam Omer