# Skrollr choppy if images are used?

Tags: ios, css, image, parallax, skrollr

I'm using the skrollr plugin to create a parallax web page for iOS.  If I just use text, it is extremely fluid, and very fast.  If I include a background image with CSS or an inline image with HTML, the scrolling suddenly becomes very choppy.  Is there a fix for this? Any image slows it down considerably.

Thanks!

Comment: do you animate the images or is it already slow if just added?

Comment: @Prinzhorn I animated the opacity and position (using CSS transform)

Comment: Have you tried it on an actual device?

Comment: How big are the images you're using? Big images will slow you down considerably when they load in (especially on mobile devices, I've found)

Comment: i worked with skrollr we have done this page http://www.pipeaporter.com/pipe-a-porter-people
it works good on device even with "big" image (not in kb)
Have you an example to show us?

Comment: with the CSS background image you will find setting `background-attachment:fixed;` helps.

Comment: `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` to enable hardware acceleration? Maybe [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529381/what-does-webkit-transform-translate3d0-0-0-exactly-do-apply-to-body) has an answer for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your background image size, css background images can impose a high cost on the rendering of any page.  This is variable but the more area you cover with a background the higher the cost - as the render engine for the browser needs to repaint larger parts of the screen.  You can see this in action if you use Chrome and use the developer tools and the timeline tools.

A fix for your specific case of animating the images maybe to do a 3d CSS transform.  IE don't do a normal transform but a 3d transform such as 'translate3d'.  This will automatically trigger hardware rendering (ie your computers gpu will handle the transform) and offload some of the overhead from your cpu - and in theory make your animation much smoother.

This comes at a cost of course, especially if your dealing with mobile or other limited platforms.  But its worth a shot.