# Strange text shown in chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome

I'm developing a website using angularjs.  There is some strange text shown in Chrome. Does anyone know why? This only happens in Chrome.  In Firefox and Safari, this doesn't happen.
[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

Comment: Please rollback your question or delete it entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question....

Actually, the right way to solve this kind issue is, add a new css attribute: `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` [see why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529381/what-does-webkit-transform-translate3d0-0-0-exactly-do-apply-to-body/18529444#18529444).