# SVG image not showing up when translate3d(0,0,0); rule is applied. Expected?

Tags: css, svg

In a Cordova app I am working on, I'd like to force hardware acceleration to render certain elements. A common way to achieve this is by using `translate3d(0,0,0)` CSS rule, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529381/what-does-webkit-transform-translate3d0-0-0-exactly-do-apply-to-body).

However, when I use this, SVG images no longer appear. Interesting part is when I use values other than 0s for `translate3d()`, for instance `translate3d(1,1,1)`, the images start appearing again.

I am not sure if this is a bug with Webkit browsers (as it's evidenced in both Chrome and Safari), or there's something about using 0's for `translate3d()` that makes SVGs no longer appear.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to try and force hardware acceleration and they change dependant on browser and device.

Here are a couple of possible ways:

```
// translateZ Transform
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
-moz-transform: translateZ(0);
-ms-transform: translateZ(0);
-o-transform: translateZ(0);
transform: translateZ(0);

// Backface Visibility
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
-ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;

// Perspective
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-moz-perspective: 1000;
-ms-perspective: 1000;
perspective: 1000;

// Translate3D transform
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

You can read up more on it here: [Increase Your Site’s Performance with Hardware-Accelerated CSS](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css)