# background-attachment: fixed; is not working in firefox

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, shopify

here is my site
https://charles-keally.myshopify.com/
Its been a whole day fixing the parallax image. The last image show parallax in chrome but not in mozilla. Please somebody help me.
I'm using debut theme.
All I did is just add
 background-attachment:fixed;
in hero.liquid
Anyone please help me
Thanks

Comment: can you please just post some codes so that we can try to understand what you have done?

Comment: it's a known issue, but not able to find the question dealing with it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you disable this on the .page-container class:

```
-ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

It should be better.

Comment: you are awsome. You made my day. Thanks Nick

Comment: While this may work, it doesn't help those who need the transforms. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Studocwho in this case translate3d(0,0,0) does nothing in terms of what you see. it moves the object by 0px in x, y and z axis. It's only a technique to force the hardware acceleration. For more information about this you can read it on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529381/what-does-webkit-transform-translate3d0-0-0-exactly-do-apply-to-body.
If you have an example in which case you need the transforms please let know. I would gladly help.

Answer (score 1):

There have been [bugs in the past](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1292499) with transformations in Firefox. After some quick searching, it looks like on your .page-container class contains some transformations that when disabled appear to solve your problem.

```
.page-container {
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: You are awsome. You made my day. Thanks a lot